# google map- oninfowindowclicklistener launch new activity

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps

i want to launch a new activity when user click the marker on the google map.however i have some problem with the function oninfowindowclicklistener..i have made a few markers on the map and i want click on it...

```js
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, form.class);
        startActivity(intent);


    })
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

  
    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.440978, 100.200227)).title("Balai Bomba dan Penyelamat Kangar"));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.445473, 100.255613)).title("Balai Bomba dan Penyelamat Arau"));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.427578, 100.278783)).title("Balai Bomba dan Penyelamat Pauh"));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.659915, 100.323910)).title("Balai Bomba dan Penyelamat Padang Besar"));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.412559, 100.190950)).title("Balai Bomba dan Penyelamat Kuala Perlis"));
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: you do not use .setoninfowindowclicklistener for adding click listener on MARKER. what you need is  map.setOnMarkerClickListener

Comment: @sandeep can you made a sample code on map.setonmarkerclicklistener because i new in this application...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

marker on click listener is

```
 mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

            Log.e("map marker", "marker is  " + marker.getTitle());

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: if you are using eclipse.. use ctrl+shift+o .... if its android studio, click on the red text and Alt+Enter.

Comment: I also suggest you add the above given code inside setupMap() method.